# Cannot quit iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Am new to Mac using Mavericks. I double clicked a js file with some node code and to my surprise the iOS Simulator pops up. I googled and found:
To quit iOS Simulator, choose iOS Simulator > Quit iOS Simulator

I have clicked on everything I can think of but there is nothing resembling this.
Is there a way to kill the process using the terminal and some command lines?

Comment: off topic--"unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." iOS Simulator presents the iPhone or iPad user interface in a window on your Mac computer. Used for testing software.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might be too obvious, but have you tried Command-Q (Quit)? That usually works for me.

If that doesn't work, try opening "Activity Monitor" and you can Force Stop a program there.

Comment: some times the simplest solution is the best solution

Answer (score 3):

In the upper left near the Apple logo, do you see iOS Simulator?  Click on that click on exit?

Otherwise you can use the Activity Monitor and kill it that way

Answer (score 0):

If "iOS Simulator" is not showing in the menu bar next to the Apple logo at the top left of the screen, click on the title bar that's at the top of the iOS Simulator window.

Answer (score 0):

May this Help you press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> key its open running application on system By selectig on task(ios smiulator) and press below button force to Quit button by this you can Quit